# How to create cinemagraphs in Objective-C using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, animated-gif

Is there a way to create your own [Cinemagraphs](http://cinemagraphs.com/about/) using AVFoundation or any other Image SDK in objective-c? I am not able to find the correct sdk or way to implement this.

I checked the documentation, but could not found anything regarding this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think, there is anything available to make this. This is made using high end animating tools I guess.

Comment: @iphonic I finally made it. Will share my solution later. ^_^

Comment: Could you provide some source or public git repo...maybe. I very interesting in this future, but have an issues.

Answer (score 0):

The AVFoundation framework provides tools for creating new compositions from different assets (videos, images, etc.). You can most likely use AVMutableComposition to achieve your desired effect. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/index.html

And you can read more about editing audio/video with AVFoundation from apple docs here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html